# How to write names of multiple authors with Shared affiliation in CHI Extended Abstracts Format?

Tags: templates, acm, affiliation

I hate asking this as there are so many similar question, but this changes for every format and every other year, and I just couldn't find the right way, so... can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Got a reply form acmtexsupport@aptaracorp.com on the matter, and thought I will share for future knowledge.
Generally, it is not recommended, but you can join authors into one block as suggested in the acmguide.pdf :

```
\author{…}
\email{…}
\author{...}
\email{…}
\affiliation{…}
```

This results though in very unesthetic formatting with only one block. What they suggested is to create several blocks, each with several writers and one affiliation.
A bit awkward, but it works well...

Example as given to me:

```
\author{First Author}
\email{author1@anotherco.edu}
\author{Second Author}
\email{author2@author.ac.uk}
\author{Third Author}
\email{author3@another.com}
\affiliation{\institution{University of Umbhali}
  \city{Pretoria} \country{South Africa}}

\author{Fourth Author}
\email{author4@another.com}
\author{Fifth Author}
\email{author5@anotherco.com}
\affiliation{\institution{University of Umbhali}
  \city{Pretoria} \country{South Africa}}

\author{Sixth Author}
\email{author6@author.fr}
\author{Seventh Author}
\email{author7@umbhaliu.ac.za}
\affiliation{\institution{University of Umbhali}
  \city{Pretoria} \country{South Africa}}
```

Hope this helps someone.
Thanks!